# Proving that $(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000} < 10^{-100}$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove  $(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000} < 10^{-100}$. The notes that I am looking at show the following steps.

$$
    (1-\sqrt{2})^{3000} < 10^{-100} \\
    1-\sqrt{2} < 10^{-1/30} \\
$$

The LHS is clearly a negative number and the RHS is positive. So the proof should be done at this point, correct?

In my lecture notes, I saw that the proof continued with the following step:
$$
    1-\sqrt{2} < 10^{-1/30} \\
    \frac{1}{(1-\sqrt{2})^{30}} > 10 \\
$$

The inequality was flipped, but I am confused why this occurred. I thought raising both sides to a negative exponent only require inequality flipping if the product of the base on both sides is positive? In this case, the LHS base is negative and the RHS base is positive, so their product is negative.

Comment: The new equation is taking each side to the -30th power, which flips the inequality.

Comment: Note that $a^n < b^n$ is *not* equivalent to $a < b$ if $a$ or $b$ is negative.

Comment: @amWhy Is this because $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$ is a decreasing function?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $(1 - \sqrt{2})^{3000} < 10^{-100}$ or that $1 - \sqrt{2} < 10^{-100}$?

Comment: @anomaly The former

Comment: Your concerns are good ones: some of these intermediate steps are not correct or not useful steps in a correct proof.

Answer (score 2):

Like this
\begin{align*}
&(1-\sqrt{2})^{3000} < 10^{-100} \\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &|1-\sqrt{2}| < 10^{-1/30}\\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &\sqrt{2}-1 < 10^{-1/30}\\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &(\sqrt{2}-1)^{-30} > 10\\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}-1)^{30}} > 10\\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &(\sqrt{2}+1)^{30} > 10\\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &(\sqrt{2}\;)^{30} > 10\\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &2^{15} > 10\\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &2^{4} > 10\\ \Longleftarrow\qquad
    &16 > 10
\end{align*}

Comment: Where did the absolute value come from? Is it because the $1-\sqrt{2}$ is negative and the exponent is even, so the LHS is originally a positive number, and we need to ensure that it stays positive when we're raising each side to $\frac{1}{3000}$?